# Issues while deploying flutter website to server

Tags: flutter, apache, deployment

I want to deploy flutter website to my own hosting server. For that i have done following steps.

```
1.  Go to the root folder of your project and do a build in release mode  flutter build web
```

The next step is to deploy that folder and host it on server. But when i perform above step the folder is generated inside build folder, but  source tree is not showing me build folder while commiting, What could be the issue here, I want to commit that folder to the branch.

2. I am going to use apache web server for flutter web deployment. will this server work with flutter website?

Update: If anyone has similar question apache worked with flutter website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build folder is usually in `.gitignore` that's why you don't see any changes after building it. After running the `flutter build web`, a `web` folder is created at `build`, this is the folder you need to upload at the `public_html` of your server. If you don't see at all the `web` folder after building, try a `flutter clean && flutter pub get` and rebuild it again.

Comment: You are correct, I have removed build folder from ignored file list and now able to see in commit listing

Comment: right now when i try to run index.html from buid/web folder it is displaying blank page, when i run the web from android studio working correctly, so if i upload that folder at public_html will i be able access my site?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing exactly? Maybe try a new thread so others can pitch in aswell.